# Increase counter by 1 each time another cell is non-zero

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

I know this is a trivial question, but I am pretty new to VBA programming and am facing a particular issue in my office. Any help is appreciated. I have a cell, the output for which comes from 100,000 simulations. I also have to track how many times out of those 100000 simulations, the cell hits a value of >0. How can I write a VBA code to track the number of times the cell has a simulation output >0?

Comment: First hit or each time to check of found >0?

Comment: Each time. So like when I run the simulation and >0 comes 23789 times, the counter value at the end of simulation should be = 23789.

Comment: What cell will be monitored? multi columns and multi rows?

Comment: Actually you can use formula, and it will be more efficient, I think

Comment: What is driving each of the simulations?  Seems like you need to hook into that and check the value at each cycle.